Why Swift always suspend when running async function even if there is no asynchronous code inside it
I have read some articles and have been told that if an async function only contains normal synchronous code, then there won't be a suspension during runtime, no switching thread,
as this article mentioned

If a suspension does not happen, no pause will take place and your function will continue to run with the same efficiency and timings as a synchronous function.
That last part carries an important side effect: using await will not cause your code to wait for one runloop to go by before continuing.

However I did a test and it seems doesn't work that way
struct ContentStructure: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomView()
        .task {
            print("task start thread = \(Thread.current)")
            await fakeExpensiveWork()
            print("task end thread = \(Thread.current)")
        }
    }
}

func fakeExpensiveWork() async {
    print("fake expensive work thread = \(Thread.current)")
}

struct CustomView: View{
    
    init(){
        print("init thread = \(Thread.current)")
    }
    
    var body: some View{
        List{
            ForEach(1..<100){ _ in
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
        }
    }
}

printed:
init thread = <_NSMainThread: 0x600001704000>{number = 1, name = main}
task start thread = <_NSMainThread: 0x600001704000>{number = 1, name = main}
fake expensive work thread = <NSThread: 0x60000176ae00>{number = 6, name = (null)}
task end thread = <_NSMainThread: 0x600001704000>{number = 1, name = main}

Compiled with:
Apple Swift version 5.10 (swiftlang-5.10.0.13 clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.6.0
As the log showed, it always switch a thread to do the fakeExpensiveWork() even if it just print a log. When I put Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10) inside the fakeExpensiveWork, the List still can be scrolled smoothly.
So is my understanding of this article incorrect, or has Apple updated the behavior of Swift?

Didn't found in yours article about thread switching

@Cy-4AH “using await will not cause your code to wait for one runloop to go by before continuing.” But in my code. those next runloops seem to go by. There is a suspension happened during await

Doesn't see runloops in your code

Because fakeExpensiveWork doesn't bound to any Actor so when it is called, your code is submit to global concurrent Excutor, then it will submit job to coorperative pool which is a group of thread managed so it depends on coorperative pool to assign your job to a particular thread, therefore we can not exactly know which thread your code is running ( a special case is MainActor when we know that our code is run on Main Thread). Take a look at this excellent blog for more explain

Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly. My question is, even if there is no real asynchronous code in async function, Swift will still treats it as a job and schedule it rather than execute it synchronously directly?

Yes, you understand correctly

But those articles said "It’s a common joke that many coding problems can be fixed by waiting for one runloop tick to pass before trying again – usually seen as DispatchQueue.main.async { … } in Swift projects – but that will not happen when using await, because the code will execute immediately.""The word potential here is very important: As just mentioned, a suspension point is only created if we’re in the wrong context; If no context hopping is needed, the code will run synchronously. This is something that DispatchQueues notoriously could not do"

Here "fakeExpensiveWork" is not boud to MainActor so an context switch is needed.

add "MainActor.assertIsolated()" in your function to learn more

If you add @MainActor to "fakeExpensiveWork" therefore no more context switch and your print statement is now run synchronously

This should be the key point that resolves my confusion. Thank you for your patience.
